# li with display: inline-block; property jumps down in Google Chrome & Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, html-lists, css

I am trying to build a website and have encountered a tricky issue with li having display: inline-block; property.

My website is: http://www.gypsytours.in/

If you visit this site, on homepage, I have a horizontal list under the heading "Himalayan Packages by Gypsy Tours".

In this list, I have a block element A with display: block; property.

Here are my simplified codes:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="menu-board">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Elephant Safari Packages in Jim Corbett Park, India</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Chopta Tungnath Trekking Package</a></li>
<li><a href="#">River Rafting Packages in Rishikesh</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#menu-board
{
    text-align: center;
}
#menu-board ul
{
}
#menu-board ul li
{
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu-board ul li a
{
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #C50000;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now, the issues is: My link-text in 2nd box, is not longer than two lines, unlike the other two boxes where link-text spreads in three lines. This boxes look perfectly fine in IE and FireFox but when I open the site in Google Chrome or Safari, the box in the center (with relatively shorter text) pops down. If I make the text long enough to span in three lines, it comes back to original position. I am not able to figure out how to fix this.  My apologies for not being able to put across my issue in simple and short manner. I am relatively inexperienced with web-designing. I will really appreciate if you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to track this down and am looking at the computed positions and actually found that Safari 5.1 drops the LAST element in the list below the others. Still looking, though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, after more digging, I found out that it was a computed float issue.

I believe that adding:

```
#splash-list ul li a {
    float:left;
}
```

will solve the problem. It may compute very slightly differently on other browsers, but at least they'll be in the proper line.

Hope this helps!

Mason

Comment: Awesome ! That worked :) Many Many thanks for your time, expertise and quick help. I have implemented your suggestion, tested with FireFox, Chrome, IE7 and IE8. Has worked smoothly so far.

Comment: i had the same issue on chrome, and float:left; resolved the problem, thanks @masonwinsauer